# ValueError : not enough values to unpack. why?

Tags: python, file, pickle

I am learning file management from a website and I tried executing a certain script but it hasn't worked out well for me.

It keeps returning this error at the line : `city, day, time = line.split()`

> ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected at least 2, got 0)

I am trying to alphabetize and pickle dump a list of cities and their time zones, the text file has several lines such as this:

```
Salt lake city Sun 09:52
San Francisco Sun 00:52
Amsterdam Sun 08:52
Denver Sun 01:52
San Salvador Sun 01:52
Detroit Sun 02:52
```

This is the code:

```
import pickle

lines = open("cities_and_times.txt").readlines()
lines.sort()

cities = []
for line in lines:
    *city, day, time = line.split()
    hours, minutes = time.split(":")
    cities.append((" ".join(city), day, (int(hours), int(minutes)) ))

    f_new = open("cities_and_times.pkl", "bw")
    pickle.dump(cities, f_new)

    print(cities)
```

Comment: Hint: What happens when you have a blank line?

Comment: You can skip blank lines with `if not line: continue`. BTW, you have an indentation problem: the stuff after the `cities.append` line shouldn't be inside the `for` loop.

Comment: A blank line, how? On the text file? There's none, but there are blank spaces between lines.

Comment: @Burhan, you were right. I did have blanks after all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need an if condition which will allow you to skip over blank lines. Something like:

```
if not line:
   continue

# Or do this

if not line:
   pass
else:
   *city, day, time = line.split()
```

Comment: Can you print the value of `line` for the iteration that it raises the error?

Comment: It works now. U were right, I had blanks at the end of the file.

Comment: your last line: should be ... line.split()

Comment: Sorry for that typo :)

Comment: @Danjoe If the blank lines are _only_ ever at the end of the file, then you can use `break` instead of `continue`, i.e., `if not line: break`, since there's no point reading any more lines if you're at the end of the data.