# ValueError: not enough values to unpack

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary, nlp, nltk, sentiment-analysis

I am trying to learn (on Python3) how to do sentiment analysis for NLP and I am using the "UMICH SI650 - Sentiment Classification" Database available on Kaggle: https://www.kaggle.com/c/si650winter11

At the moment I am trying to generate a vocabulary with some loops, here is the code:

```
    import collections
    import nltk
    import os

    Directory = "../Databases"


    # Read training data and generate vocabulary
    max_length = 0
    freqs = collections.Counter()
    num_recs = 0
    training = open(os.path.join(Directory, "train_sentiment.txt"), 'rb')
    for line in training:
        if not line:
            continue
        label, sentence = line.strip().split("\t".encode())
        words = nltk.word_tokenize(sentence.decode("utf-8", "ignore").lower())
        if len(words) > max_length:
            max_length = len(words)
        for word in words:
            freqs[word] += 1
        num_recs += 1
    training.close()
```

I keep getting this error, that I don't fully understand:

> in  label, sentence = line.strip().split("\t".encode())
>   ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 2, got 1)

I tried to add

```
if not line:
        continue
```

like suggested in here: [ValueError : not enough values to unpack. why?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45270021/valueerror-not-enough-values-to-unpack-why)
But it didn't work for my case. How can I solve this error?

Thanks a lot in advance,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a cleaner way to read the dataset from https://www.kaggle.com/c/si650winter11

**Firstly**, context manager is your friend, use it, http://book.pythontips.com/en/latest/context_managers.html

**Secondly**, if it's a text file, avoid reading it as a binary, i.e. `open(filename, 'r')` not `open(filename, 'rb')`, then there's no need to mess with str/byte and encode/decode.

**And now**:

```
from nltk import word_tokenize
from collections import Counter
word_counts = Counter()
with open('training.txt', 'r') as fin:
    for line in fin:
        label, text = line.strip().split('\t')
        # Avoid lowercasing before tokenization.
        # lowercasing after tokenization is much better
        # just in case the tokenizer uses captialization as cues. 
        word_counts.update(map(str.lower, word_tokenize(text)))

print(word_counts)
```

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to resolve this would be to put the unpacking statement into a `try/except` block. Something like:

```
try:
    label, sentence = line.strip().split("\t".encode())
except ValueError:
    print(f'Error line: {line}')
    continue
```

My guess is that some of your lines have a label with nothing but whitespace afterwards.

Comment: The thing I noticed is that by doing so, it prints every single line. Does this mean that every line shows such kind of error? is this "normal"?

Comment: @iraciv94 Your call to `split` isn't producing a list longer than a single element. This means the delimiter you're specifying (`"\t".encode()`) isn't present in your lines. You need to find the correct delimiter. Did you try just using `"\t"`?

Answer (score 0):

You should check for the case where you have the wrong number of fields:

```
 if not line:
     continue
 fields = line.strip().split("\t".encode())
 if len(fields) != 2:
     # you could print(fields) here to help debug
     continue
 label, sentence = fields
```